# Совершенствование в C: программы для написания

Tags: c

Что посоветуете чтобы лучше научиться программировать на Си?

Изучил всю теорию по Си, сделал все упражнения из учебника, какие программы посоветуете написать на Си, чтобы научится программировать.

Comment: писать код не пробовали? очень помогает научиться.

Comment: Попробуйте написать аналог утилиты `more` с возможностью вывода двоичного файла в режиме дампа (как в `hd`), поиском двоичных данных и произвольного перемещения по файлу (как по смещениям, так и по номерам строк).

Comment: Уэзерелл "Этюды для программистов"

Comment: @alexlz, да, Уэзерелл  это отличная книжка. 

Сейчас посмотрел в гугле и порадовался, что она доступна.

А вот [интервью](http://demin.ws/blog/russian/2012/08/25/interview-with-charles-wetherell/) с ним, наверное интересно.

Comment: Как насчёт изучения C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я для этих целей купил книжку Н.Культин - С/С++ в задачах и примерах. В этом задачнике есть задачи и их решения. На иногда я просто открываю случайную страницу и решаю задачу которая попадется не подглядывая в ее решение, если ничего не получается то только тогда подглядываю в ответ.